# Replace free space with bytes in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to replace free space with bytes,then delete those wipes so that by this I do what is called " Wipe Free Space " ..I knew how to replace a file with bytes using the code below then delete it..But the idea of **replacing free space with bytes** is somehow difficult for me..

```
 outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
 outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
 outputStream.close();
```

Comment: You mean wipe the hard drive?

Comment: yeah,wipe the free space in hard drive of Android Device

Answer (score 0):

In any file, there may be whitespaces, special characters or anything else. But the idea of freespace occurring in between the content of a  file isn't really possible. Now the question is: how are you defining 'free space'? Is this data that exists within the file-content that you find as redundant or irrelevant?

Comment: When you delete a file, Windows removes the reference to that file, but doesn't delete the actual data that made up the file on your hard drive.